# What alternatives do I have for Directions API other than Google Maps and MapQuest?

Tags: google-maps, routing, api, mapquest

I need an API, other than the two below that, given the starting point and possibly the ending point, will re-order a list of waypoints by the shortest, fastest or optimized route:

- **[Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)**
- **[MapQuest Directions API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/directions-ws)**

Comment: Worldwide or a specific area? Only webservices or do you also look for software to install on your own server?

Comment: For now I'll just need it for Portugal but it must be extensible for the rest of Europe and ultimately world wide.
Webservice and/or software to install.

Comment: ViaMichelin API http://www.viamichelin.pt/ developer site http://dev.viamichelin.com/ for the REST/Javascript API's